# Paralelizar 2 funciones para 1 data.frame

Tags: r

He estado buscando información sobre paralelizar procesos en R y he estado trasteando con los paquetes "parallel", "foreach" y "doParallel" pero no he conseguido los resultados que quería. Me gustaría poder hacer 2 funciones a la vez para reducir tiempo de computación, ya que solo estoy usando un núcleo del procesador y me tarda mucho en correr el código.

Os pongo un ejemplo, tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
data= data.frame(V1=rnorm(1000),V2=rnorm(1000),V3=rnorm(1000))
```

Y quiero hacer las siguientes funciones paralelamente:

```
colMeans(data)
colSums(data)
```

Lo mejor (creo) seria que cada núcleo trabajara con 1 función pero no se si siempre tienen que funcionar así los procesos de este tipo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## El problema

Los paquetes con los que lo estás intentando logran ejecutar el código en múltiples hilos haciendo SIMD (Single Instruction, Multiple Data). Por eso son apropiados cuando vas a usar **la misma función** en cada parte de una estructura de datos. 
Un ejemplo típico de uso: pasar una misma función a cada elemento de la lista x y presentar el resultado como una lista con el mismo largo que x. Usando `%dopar%` la función se pasa por más de un elemento al mismo tiempo y (en algunos casos) se reduce el tiempo de ejecución.

Lo importante es que son datos diferentes (ejp. cada columna de un data.frame) y la misma función.

En tu caso lo que estás buscando es lo contrario, mismos datos, dos funciones diferentes.

No creo que vayas a tener los resultados que estás buscando con los paquetes que estás usando, porque son para otra cosa.

En tu caso lo que te interesa es hacer MISD

## Posibles soluciones

> Nota: la ejecución en paralelo tiene el potencial de acortar el tiempo de ejecución, pero no siempre es así. Al ejecutar en paralelo tenemos un overhead: hay que abrir los hilos y después reunir el resultado. Si la/s funciones que estás ejecutando no se demoran mucho las pérdidas por overhead pueden ser más altas que la ganancia por paralelismo. En ese caso no vale la pena paralelizar.

### Aplicar cada función en parelelo

Una posible solución es no usar `colMeans` y `rowMeans` y hacer un iterador paralelo. Si estás usando Mac o Linux es facilísimo con la familia de funciones `mc*apply`. Si usas Windows con `foreach` podrías hacer algo así:

```
foo <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(1000),V2=rnorm(1000),V3=rnorm(1000))

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# Registro un cluster con dos hilos. 
registerDoParallel(makeCluster(2))

foreach(col = seq_along(foo)) %dopar% mean(foo[,col])
```

Acá estarías corriendo en dos hilos la función `mean()` sobre cada columna. En este caso en particular, con tres columnas y sabiendo que `colMeans` está optimizada y `mean()` no, seguramente el resultado va a ser más lento.

Seguirías sin poder ejecutar las medias de columnas y filas al mismo tiempo, pero si en lugar de `mean()` estás trabajando con una función con un tiempo de ejecución largo podrías usar esta estrategia para acelerar el procesamiento.

### Explorar el paquete `future`

Hay un paquete que se llama `future` e introduce algunos conceptos nuevos en R, incluyendo el de futuros. De este modo rompe la linealidad en la ejecución del código y permite explotar el paralelismo en casos distintos los de `parallel`, que es la librería que está en la base de la aproximación SIMD en R.

Esta función produce una lista con dos vectores, uno de `colSums()` y otro de `rowSums()`. Al usar el esquema `future({}) %plan% multiprocess` y luego `value()` cada función debería ejecutarse en un hilo separado.

```
library(future)
media_columnas_filas <- function(x) {
  columnas <- future({colMeans(x)}) %plan% multiprocess
  filas <- future({rowMeans(x)}) %plan% multiprocess
  list(filas_final = value(columnas), 
       columnas_final = value(filas))
  }
```

En las pruebas que hice se ejecuta un poco más lento que con

```
list (columnas = colMeans(x), 
         filas = rowMeans(x))
```

Pero se podría probar con otros datos (más grandes), otro hardware u otras funciones. De hecho en algunas pruebas con más funciones anidadas corre un poco más rápido que la versión sincrónica.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta, me has ayudado un monton! :)